# How can a newbie product support engineer make themselves more valuable to potential recruiters?

Tags: software-industry, india, tech-support, nepal

Out of college, I had just 1 job for 1 Year. Discount the probation period(training period), I've only 6 months of experience. My current salary is around 250$ per month. I was applying with expectation of 500$ per month to another company (for the same role).

The job description includes:

- linux
- networking concepts, dns, web servers, email servers, c-panel
- deploying solutions to aws/azure/google cloud.
- 1 YOE as product support engineer.

My question is recruiters find it "off-putting" given my salary expectations for my YOE. How can I change this? How can I make myself worth more? Given that I don't have much YOE, will certifications (Like AWS SAA, RHCSA etc) help me? What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's understandable to want a higher salary, especially as you gain more experience and skills.
Beyond just studying for certifications, try to gain practical experience by working on real-world projects or contributing to open-source projects. This hands-on experience will not only solidify your understanding but also demonstrate your ability to apply your knowledge in practical scenarios.

Comment: If you're going to contribute to open source, for this purpose, pick one project and make a _significant_ contribution to it. The first thing an interviewer is going to ask about open source work is what you contributed, and if that's just fixing a typo in the documentation it isn't likely to impress anyone, even if it is useful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you likely are out of luck - and there is a big chance this will never change.

Let me start: You have 6 months experience and want now a new job for double the money. Recruiters tell you - and that should be quite a number please - that this is too high. There is little chance they all lie (but you should do your research) - but chance is you just price yourself out of the market. Training counts, and you can work on that, but experience also counts, and you cannot just read websites for that. There is a good chance you just want more than the market bears.

Now the really bad news:

One, a lot of the world is hitting a recession. This means many international companies have cut down on hiring, so companies providing services for them also will not hire. This may take anywhere from 1 to 5 years if history is a factor. As a total junior, that has a serious implication on your marketability, lots of people with a lot better resumes are looking for work. College is not really impressive when people with university degree look for work.

And here is the real bummer. By the time that is over, a LOT of jobs in your area are DONE. Never to reappear. AI is already doing a lot of remote customer service work - and there is NO implication it cannot do IT support remotely, especially after the timeframe I gave for the recession. Certain professions already are disappearing (lower-level graphics design, customer service, call center, translations, copywriting) and higher level jobs are getting way more productive (programming, i.e.) so less people are needed. Give it another 3-5 years (which is how long the problems in the west may take) and you may be surprised. Anything that CAN be done remote will soon be done remote by AI. And that includes i.e. phone calls - one of my companies is just now working on implementing an outgoing customer retention system that CALLS the client. All AI.

So, in short:

Long term: Career prospectes disappear within half to one decade BEST case for you - quite likely faster. And yes, that actually includes physical work.
Short term: there is a recession in many countries with hiring freezes.

All that means you likely just want more money. Remember, it is not about YOU (well, for you it is), but about OTHERS. If someone else with similar qualification match works cheaper, what you want does not matter. Value is established by the buyer, not the seller.

But essentially there are people that say within 5 years the Indian software industry will be in shambles. And it is not just that.

So, for now - get experience, and do not care about the money. You obviously have short term priced yourself out.

Answer (score -1):

There is a great deal of free training materials online.

Review and practice as much as you can.

Become an expert in an area or two.

Certifications are helpful with demonstratable skills.

Comment: Cert exams are expensive compared to my salary  in Nepal. Example the ccna costs 300 USD and my monthly salary is < 300  USD. I'd love project based ideas like in web development where you can build projects to showcase your talent in this field of devops/linuxadmin...

Comment: If you can't afford certs, you can take the tutorials to be skilled. Be prepared to answer questions.  Azure, etc. will let you sign up and get a certain amount of free credit. If used carefully you can use to demo skills.

Comment: If you're going to down vote my answer, then offer a better one!

Comment: I've not downvoted.

Comment: @barnyard9 I am sorry, I didn't mean you specificly. I mean whoever downvoted and didn't explain why.